# Xcode IAP SKProductsRequest start method call don't show exception in output window

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am pretty new with xcode and objective c. I am trying to implement IAP functionalities. I implement store handler class and there is some code for review :)

[image]

In implementation class a have implemented required handler method

```
 -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
```

[image]

I am sure that exception is raised by **[productsRequest start];** method because when I remove it nothing happens and there is no exception.
When I call **[productsRequest start];** method exception come up in main method. A exception is rised after 2 or 3 seconds after **[productsRequest start];** method invoked and come up in main method.

[image]

A exception is raised after 2 or 3 seconds after **[productsRequest start];** method invoked and come up in main method.
I can not see any exception detail in output console and I cant understand why is happening. If I could see some error message that would be nice and very helpfuly :)
I am new in xcode and objective-c and IAP so dont have any idea what o do now :)

Please help people!

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Put the actual text of the relevant code (and properly formatted) into your question.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug your crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was fighting through a very similar issue. I was using an IAP helper to build up the request.

My issue turned out to be retaining the instance of my IAP helper. When the data had loaded, it tried to call the delegate, but the original object had been released.

Since the entire IAP mechanism is a black box; the exception occurs outside developer's code because the object created and handed off to the IAP request is no longer there for it to target.